# AWS S3 Bucket concumed but objects doesn't appear

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud

I have tried to upload an VMDK image using `ec2-import-instance` twice but due to network trouble upload has been interrupted. Instead of resuming I have fired again same command `ec2-import-instance`. Second upload was also interrupted. Now it appears two import process when I fire `ec2-describe-conversion-tasks`. I have cancelled both the tasks using `ec2-cancel-conversion-task`. Now when I am firing `ec2-describe-conversion-tasks` it shows status of both as CANCELLED - so now all the import and everything has been cleared from s3 bucket right! But still when I see the size of S3 bucket it shows consumed 11GB but objects I can see only of size less than few MBs. So my questions are:

- How to check where these hidden objects used space?
- How to reclaim these space promptly?